# Syntax error in SQLCMD SQL script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sqlcmd

I'm currently trying to get a SQL script working for SQL Server 2005. I'm using `SQLCMD` to execute the script and it fails giving me an "Error: Syntax error at line 7 near command ':r'" error.

The script:

```
--Main Script--
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

:on error exit

:r C:\Documents and Settings\ZSmith\My Documents\Scripts\CreateDatabase
:r C:\Documents and Settings\ZSmith\My Documents\Scripts\CreateTables
```

I can provide the other SQL scripts if needed but they function fine on their own. I'm just trying to automate the entire process.

Comment: Why the downvote? Could you at least tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, you need to

- put the SQL file name into double quotes - especially if the path contains spaces!
- include the `.sql` extension on the file name

Try this:

```
:r "C:\Documents and Settings\ZSmith\My Documents\Scripts\CreateDatabase.sql"
:r "C:\Documents and Settings\ZSmith\My Documents\Scripts\CreateTables.sql"
```